# How do I create dynamic key names for JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, jasmine

**TL;DR;**

I expect this code

```
console.log Object.defineProperty(results,match, {value:[]})
```

to output something like:

```
[foo: Array[0]]
```

This works in console, but not in my code that is being tested by Jasmine.

**Details**

I am trying to create a JavaScript hash. I can't seem to dynamically create properties in my code, although I was able to do it in JSFiddle. I am writing the tests first, and the code seems to fail under Jasmine. I don't know if this is the fault of Jasmine or not.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb1eyt8j/). I am using Object.defineProperty to define the property for the first time, but I also tried:

```
if typeof results[match] = 'undefined' then results[match] = []
```

and that didn't work either. In my Jasmine code, it doesn't create the property.

Comment: isn't the standard way to do this `results[match] = results[match] || [];` This is faster than an if

Comment: I am calling .push on the array. if the array doesn't exist, that is, if the dynamic property hasn't been defined as an array on the results array, JavaScript complains that push isn't a method of "results".

Comment: @Hogan: `results[match] ?= [ ]` would probably be more idiomatic CoffeeScript. I suspect that any speed differences would be vanishingly small, no?

Comment: @muistooshort - agreed

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of minor things (several mentioned in the comments above), corrections are in the code comments:

```
testsForRev = [{
    id: 1
    rev_id: 10
    is_current: true
    test_params: [
      {name: 'device_param1', value: '1/#{1PLACEHOLDER1}'}
      {name: 'device_param2', value: 'TEST/#{2PLACEHOLDER2}/#{3PLACEHOLDER3}'}
      {name: 'test_param1', value: 'NOT_A_PLACEHOLDER'}
    ]
  },{
    id: 2
    rev_id: 10
    test_params: [
      {name: 'device_param3', value: '1/#{4PLACEHOLDER4}'}
      {name: 'device_param4', value: 'TEST/#{5PLACEHOLDER5}/#{6PLACEHOLDER6}'}
      {name: 'test_param2', value: 'NOT_A_PLACEHOLDER'}
      {name: 'device_param7', value: '5/#{4PLACEHOLDER4}'}
    ]
  }]

parseDeviceParams= (test,results) ->
    for param in test.test_params
        param.value.replace /#{(.*?)}/g, (str,match,start, usage) ->

            #conditionally create array for the property. Alternative
            #would be 'results[match] and results[match].push...'
            #which would conditionally activate but not create the
            #empty array if not already present...
            results[match] ?= []
            results[match].push {name: param.name, usage: usage}

            #i've added a return value for the substr, but you were
            #calling just for side effects?
            return match

    return results

aggregate = {} #changed to object, now need to define custom toString

Object.defineProperty aggregate, 'toString',
    value: ->
        str = ''
        for index, value of this
            str += "#{index}: "
            for item in value
                for key, val of item
                    str += "\t#{key}: #{val}\n"

        return str

for test in testsForRev
    parseDeviceParams test, aggregate
console.log "results:\n#{aggregate.toString()}"
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n44cvgm5/)